# Frequency weighted least square estimation

Tags: modeling, matlab

I recently realised an RLS Algorithm which fit a stepresponse of a system with an underdamped complex pole pair.

Now i realised that there is a bias for some kind of responses i get. I found out that using an estimation based on weighting the frequency range where the input spectrum has the most power, gives me a much more accure and stable parameter set. (tryed on Matlab Toolbox arx command , with focus: simulation)

Now the question, is there a descrpition how to implement this method? Which things of the LS / RLS algorithm do i have to alter and how?Are there Papers, Sources available from Mathworks?

Bye and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are proposing has a long history under the name of spectral regression. You can find book-length treatments where this approach is used, by Dhrymes and Hannan, among others. "Googling" for "spectral regression" will yield hits such as [Engle's band spectrum regression paper of 1974](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2526084), among many others. Other terms you may google for are "Hannan inefficient" or  "band spectrum regression".